# Subject and Observable, how to delete item, filter() list and next()

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable, rxjs5, subject-observer

I have a list of songs setup with Subject and Observable (shown with `| async` in view), and now I want to delete a song off the list, do some `filter()` and call `next()` on the Subject.

**How and where do I filter?** Right now I am doing `getValue()` on Subject and passing that to `next()` on, well, Subject. This just seems wrong and circularish.

I also tried subscribing to the Subject and getting the data that way, filtering it and calling `next()` inside `subscribe()`, but I got a RangeError.

I could filter the Observable by storing all deleted id's. The Subject's list then becomes out of sync by having deleted songs on there and also every observer would have to have the deleted-id's-list which seems ludicrous. I'm rapidly growing old and mental. Please help me internet :(

```
export class ArtistComponent implements OnInit {
  private repertoire$;
  private repertoireSubject;
  constructor(
    private route: ActivatedRoute,
    private service: ArtistService
  ) {
    this.getRepertoire().subscribe(
      songs => this.repertoireSubject.next(songs)
    );
  }

  getRepertoire() {
    return this.route.paramMap
      .switchMap((params: ParamMap) =>
      this.service.fetchRepertoire(params.get('id')));
  }

  //THIS IS WHERE I'M HAVING TROUBLE
  delete(id): void {
    this.repertoireSubject.next(
      this.repertoireSubject.getValue().filter(song => (song.id !== id))
    );
    // TODO remove song from repertoire API
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.repertoireSubject = new BehaviorSubject<any>(null);
    this.repertoire$ = this.repertoireSubject.asObservable();
  }

}
```

Comment: yeah you should have something like an array of your songs, otherwise it can get pretty difficult.

Comment: @trichetriche so how would that solve the issue of the Subject being out of sync once a song is deleted? I'm thinking there must be some way of filtering that I haven't figured out

Comment: Okay, I'm making an answer, wiat a minute please

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i recommand you to create new attribute on your component, where you will last store state. (here understands array of songs).

Is always better conceptualize your code by, internal property who represent your state (or store) and another attribute who have the role to sync rest of your application (by observable / event).

Another tips is to strong type your code by model. Will be easier to debug and maintain.

Then you just have to update it according to your logic and next on your Subject

```
export interface SongModel {
        id: number;
        title: string;
        artiste: string;
    }

    export class ArtistComponent implements OnInit {
        private repertoire$ : Observable<SongModel[]>;
        private repertoireSubject: BehaviorSubject<SongModel[]>;
        //Array of song, should be same type than repertoireSubject.
        private songs: SongModel[];

        constructor(
            private route: ActivatedRoute,
            private service: ArtistService
        ) {

            //We push all actual references.
            this.getRepertoire().subscribe(
                songs => {
                    this.songs = songs;
                    this.repertoireSubject.next(this.songs);
                }
            );
        }

        ngOnInit() {
            //Because is suject of array, you should init by empty array.
            this.repertoireSubject = new BehaviorSubject<SongModel[]>([]);
            this.repertoire$ = this.repertoireSubject.asObservable();
        }


        getRepertoire() {
            return this.route.paramMap
                .switchMap((params: ParamMap) =>
                this.service.fetchRepertoire(params.get('id')));
        }

        //THIS IS WHERE I'M HAVING TROUBLE
        delete(id: number): void {
            // Update your array referencial.
            this.songs = this.songs.filter(songs => songs.id !== id);
            // Notify rest of your application.
            this.repertoireSubject.next(this.songs);
        }
    }
```

Comment: thanks! This is the most clean to me, although I had become stuck on the idea that the whole thing could be done with only Observable-filters. I will implement this and strongly type the models.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep everything in streams then you could take a page from the Redux playbook and do something like this:

```js
const actions = new Rx.Subject();

const ActionType = {
  SET: '[Song] SET',
  DELETE: '[Song] DELETE'
};

const songs = [
  { id: 1, name: 'First' },
  { id: 2, name: 'Second' },
  { id: 3, name: 'Third' },
  { id: 4, name: 'Fourth' },
  { id: 5, name: 'Fifth' }
];

actions
.do(x => { console.log(x.type, x.payload); })
.scan((state, action) => {
  switch(action.type) {
    case ActionType.SET:
     return action.payload;
    case ActionType.DELETE:
      return state.filter(x => x.id !== action.payload);
  }
  return state;
}, [])
.subscribe(x => { console.log('State:', x); });


window.setTimeout(() => {
  actions.next({ type: ActionType.SET, payload: songs });
}, 1000);

window.setTimeout(() => {
  actions.next({ type: ActionType.DELETE, payload: 2 });
}, 2000);

window.setTimeout(() => {
  actions.next({ type: ActionType.DELETE, payload: 5 });
}, 3000);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rxjs/5.5.7/Rx.min.js"></script>
```

Or something like this:

```js
const deletes = new Rx.Subject();

const songs = Rx.Observable.of([
  { id: 1, name: 'First' },
  { id: 2, name: 'Second' },
  { id: 3, name: 'Third' },
  { id: 4, name: 'Fourth' },
  { id: 5, name: 'Fifth' }
]);

window.setTimeout(() => {
  deletes.next(2);
}, 1000);

window.setTimeout(() => {
  deletes.next(5);
}, 2000);

songs.switchMap(state => {
  return deletes.scan((state, id) => {
    console.log('Delete: ', id);
   return state.filter(x => x.id !== id);
  }, state)
  .startWith(state);
}).subscribe(x => { console.log('State:', x); });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rxjs/5.5.7/Rx.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you! This code is good, I'm sure, but looks a little too foreign to me, still getting the hang of angular, so Redux will be in the future. Thanks for taking the time :)

Answer (score 0):

If you stop relying on the async pipe and use a variable to handle your songs, it gets way easier :

```js
import { filter } from 'rxjs/operators';
export class ArtistComponent implements OnInit {
  private songs: any;

  constructor(
    private route: ActivatedRoute,
    private service: ArtistService
  ) {
    this.getRepertoire().subscribe(songs => this.songs = songs);
  }

  getRepertoire() {
    return this.route.paramMap
      .switchMap((params: ParamMap) =>
        this.service.fetchRepertoire(params.get('id')));
  }

  delete(id): void {
    this.songs = this.songs.filter(song => song.id !== id);
  }
}
```

This way, you can simply filter like it is a simple array of object.

Comment: I think you want a `this.songs = this.songs.filter(...)` since it isn't an in-place operation.

Comment: Thank you for noticing !

Comment: Thanks for your answer, @trichetriche. I really want to learn and use the Subject/Observer pattern, so I'm gonna go with another solution. Thanks for taking the time :)

Comment: Just because you want to learn it doesn't mean you have to use it. But I get your point, good luck !