# how to delete item from angular datasource

Tags: angular, rxjs6

I have a datasource in my angular app that is populated by and HTTP service/call. I am able to get the data from the remote server, build the table in real time with that data and edit it. I want now to be able to delete a row from the data table just locally, not pushing the change back to the server. But I can't see where I am able to access the array of data. I know it must be stored in an array somewhere, but where? A zillion different console logs have brought me no closer to figuring out where the data actually is so I can manipulate it. My observer works fine to give me the data to display. Here is the code to the datasource:

```
import { Aircraft } from '../shared/aircraft';
import { AircraftInfoService } from './aircraft-info.service';
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs';
import { CollectionViewer, DataSource } from '@angular/cdk/collections';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { of } from 'rxjs';
import { catchError, finalize } from 'rxjs/operators';

export class AircraftInfoDataSource implements DataSource<Aircraft> {

  private className: string;

  private aircraftDBSubject = new BehaviorSubject<any[]>([]);
  private loadingSubject = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(false);

  public loading$ = this.loadingSubject.asObservable();

  constructor(private aircraftInfoService: AircraftInfoService) {
    this.className = this.constructor.toString().match(/\w+/g)[1];

  }

  connect(collectionViewer: CollectionViewer): Observable<Aircraft[]> {
      return this.aircraftDBSubject.asObservable();
  }

  disconnect(collectionViewer: CollectionViewer): void {
      this.aircraftDBSubject.complete();
      this.loadingSubject.complete();
  }

  getAllAircraftData() {

      this.loadingSubject.next(true);

      this.aircraftInfoService.getAllAircraftRecords().pipe(
        catchError(() => of([])),
        finalize(() => this.loadingSubject.next(false))
      )
      .subscribe((data:any[]) => this.aircraftDBSubject.next(data));
  }

  deleteAircraft( deviceID: string ) {
    console.log(this.className, ' going to delte aircraft: ', deviceID);
    console.log('aircraftDBSubject: ', this.aircraftDBSubject);
    const foundIndex = this.aircraftDBSubject.value.findIndex(x => x.id === this.deviceID);
    console.log('foundIndex=',foundIndex);

  }
}
```

The deleteAircraft function is where I'm having my issue. Here also is the data service that retrieves the data:

```
import { Aircraft } from '../shared/aircraft';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';


@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AircraftInfoService {
  aircraft: Aircraft[];
  getApi = 'https://<removed>';

  constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient) {

  }

  ngOnInit() {
    console.log('aircraftInfoservice');
  }

  getAllAircraftRecords() {
    return this.httpClient.get(this.getApi)
  }
}
```

So everything is working read-only, how can I fix it so I can write (i.e. delete records) as well?

Thanks....

Comment: find the references of  `connect` function.

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49385487/subject-and-observable-how-to-delete-item-filter-list-and-next) might be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

**Hey Dude...**

Here is my suggestion. Try to split the value from the service level. So that in your component it will be easy to handle any event.

find the sample below.

**Service Code**

```
getAllAircraftRecords(): Observable<any> {
        return this.httpService.post(this.getApi)
            .pipe(map(res => res),
            map((res: Response) => res),
            catchError((error: Response) => Observable.throw(error)));
    }
```

**Component**

```
       getAllAircraftData() {

              this.loadingSubject.next(true);        
              this.aircraftInfoService.getAllAircraftRecords().subscribe(
                        data => {
                          this.aircraftDB=data;
                          this.loadingSubject.next(false); 
                        },
                        err => {
                            this.loadingSubject.next(false); 
                        });
          }

deleteAircraft( deviceID: string ) {
   this.aircraftDB = this.aircraftDB.filter(x=>x.deviceID!=deviceID);

  }
```

this.aircraftDB you can use it for binding.

Hope this helps...